# Stored procedure returning null value to parameter during creating a new user

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a button to add a user, if I click that button, a popup is shown add user, but while saving, I get an exception that the user id was not supplied to the stored procedure.

In table, login user id is `int not null`.

I kept a debugger and tried `@userid` is null. And procedure is expecting a parameter `@userid`; where I am going wrong?

```
alter Procedure logins
    @UserId varchar(50),
    @UserName Varchar(100),
    @FirstName Varchar(100),
    @LastName Varchar(100),
    @Email Varchar(200),
    @Password Varchar(100), 
    @AllNames Varchar(max) 
As 
Begin 
    if @UserId is Null
        Insert into logins (UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Role, DateCreated, DateModified, Password, Allnames)
        Values (@UserName, @FirstName, @LastName, @Email, 'Admin', GetDate(), GetDate(), @Password, @allnames) 
    Else 
        Update logins
        Set UserName = @UserName,
            FirstName = @FirstName,
            LastName = @LastName,
            AssignedGroups = @Allnames
        Where
            UserId = @UserId 
End
```

Any stored procedure problem, any suggestions to change my stored procedure

ideas??

suggestions??

Comment: You haven't shown your code that calls the procedure.

Comment: Also: 1. **never store passwords as plaintext in a database!** - store salted hashes instead. 2. Use `MERGE` ("upsert") instead of `IF ... INSERT ELSE UPDATE` as it's a single atomic statement. 3. Your `UPDATE` statement doesn't update the `DateModified` value. 4. If you're storing human-readable text you should use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` for Unicode support ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139551/how-do-i-set-a-sql-server-unicode-nvarchar-string-to-an-emoji-or-supplementary ) - you can't store emoji in `varchar` columns, for example.

Comment: The error has to do with the c# code calling the SP not the SP. Show that code.

Comment: I have some logic written in update , some columns wont be updated, only i have a problem with creating user

Comment: Few things to confirm 
1- You mentioned in above post in Table Logins -> UserId is INT NOT NULL but your stored proc is "@UserId varchar(50),"
2- Check in Logins table UserId is auto generated or not if not than you need to supply in insert statement

Comment: And your passwords should NEVER be stored in plain text. Those values should be salted and hashed.

Comment: Well i think i have to insert user also

Comment: I cannot stress enough: DO NOT STORE PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS!. Also, DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS ENCRYPTED IN A WAY YOU CAN DECRYPT. You should 100% be looking for an existing solution for security, because home-rolled versions are highly insecure. There's no possible way for you to know all of the issues you need to guard against. 

Consider a third party for authentication, like logging in with Google/Facebook or a more enterprise-y solution like Okta.

Comment: @James 1. Show the table definition for User. 2. Show the C# code calling the stored proc. 3. You say your UserID on the table is an int, but the parameter in your stored proc is a Varchar. This makes no sense.

Comment: If the `userId` column in the table is an `int` - why is the parameter a `varchar(50)` ?? Doesn't make any sense..... ALso: when you **insert** your data, you're not providing a value for `UserId` in the table - how is that value generated / supplied??

Comment: Post C# code please

Comment: @marc_s Yes u wer Right, i modified both to int and its working fine thanx

Comment: @devil_coder Yes U were Correct i modified both to int its working fine thanks..

Answer (score 0):

User id int = null is working fine, I am able to insert.

```
alter Procedure logins
    @UserId int = null
    @UserName Var char(100),
    @FirstName Var char(100),
    @LastName Var char(100),
    @Email Var char(200),
    @Password Var char(100), 
    @AllNames Var char(max) 
As 
Begin 
    if @User Id is Null
        Insert into logins (UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Role, Date Created, Date Modified, Password, All names)
        Values (@User Name, @FirstName, @LastName, @Email, 'Admin', Get Date(), Get Date(), @Password, @allnames) 
    Else 
        Update logins
        Set User Name = @UserName,
            First Name = @FirstName,
            Last Name = @LastName,
            All Names = @Allnames
        Where
            UserId = @UserId 
End
```